# How do you access this property from the OwinStartup file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I'm creating an ASP.NET Identity 2.1 WebAPI service. It allows for registration, logging in and authorizing authtokens. In the Owin startup class that I have created following [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) is the following code:

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);

        ConfigureWebApi(httpConfig);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);

        // Plugin the OAuth bearer JSON Web Token tokens generation and Consumption will be here
    }

    private void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

Now, in the ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration method, a DbContext and UserManager are created. My question: how do I access this dbContext and UserManager in a different class in my WepAPI project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AppDbContext context = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<AppDbContext>();
AppUserManager userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<AppUserManager();
```

The same way the AccountController (in the sample project) retrieves these values.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, this did not work for me before, but I guess I had to rebuild my project.